# How to convert 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm' to hh:mm:ss (without am or pm) in java?

Tags: java, date, time, format

I want the convert the string like `1/15/2014  9:57:03 AM` or `1/15/2014  5:49:39 PM` to `9:57:03` and `17:49:39`

Comment: Dont convert the string. get the time by using getTime().

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html . Take a close look at substring and indexOf

Comment: use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: @Baby Bad idea. This question was asked after the advent of [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) which we prefer for date and time work. The `SimpleDateFormat` class that you link to was a notorious troublemaker.

Comment: `LocalDateTime.parse("1/15/2014  9:57:03 AM", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/uuuu  h:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH)) .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm:ss"))`. Please extract the two formatters into constants and also break the functionality up into a couple of statements.

Answer (score 10):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US);
Date date = format.parse("1/15/2014 9:57:03 AM");
format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String dateString = format.format(date);
```

BTW, use Google next time

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

In March 2014, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) supplanted the legacy date-time API. Since then, it has been strongly recommended to switch to `java.time`, the modern date-time API.

Your date-time string does not have time-zone information; therefore, parse it to a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) using a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). Then, format the obtained `LocalDateTime` into a string using another `DateTimeFormatter` with the desired format.

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/uuuu  h:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

// Test
Stream.of(
        "1/15/2014  9:57:03 AM",
        "1/15/2014  5:49:39 PM"
).forEach(s -> {
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(s, parser);
    String formatted = ldt.format(formatter);
    System.out.println(formatted);
});
```

**Output:**

```
9:57:03
17:49:39
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/Id7pog)

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**

Comment: Good to know modern Date-Time version of this problem, bookmarked !!

Answer (score -1):

Use ("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") for AM/PM

Comment: Thank you for wanting to contribute. For your answer to make sense you would at least need to tell us which date-time library and/or class you assume for parsing (java.time, Joda-Time, Time4J or something else). I also suspect that your answer will not work, but without the requested information I can neither know nor try it out. So please amend your answer. A full line of code for creating the thing you use for parsing would be nice. Also some explanation would help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35084160)